# Name Splitting and Comparison

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation where I need to do the following:

Company Name:

```
a. Split text before and after “ - “
b. Generate the report where texts before and after “ - “ matches = exact match
c. Generate the report where texts before and after “ - “ matches = similar matches
```

I could reach till point b. wherein I could get the results having same firsthalf and secondhalf (e.g. abc,inc. - abc,inc.) name using the following -

```
RTRIM(substring(c.companyname,0,charindex('-',c.companyname)))= LTRIM(substring(c.companyname, charindex('-',c.companyname,0)+1, len(c.companyname)))
```

However, i am unable to do the next report (e.g. abc. - abc OR abc, inc - abc)

Could anybody help?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Name
Walt Disney - Walt Disney
Fun Food - Fun Food
Fun Food, Inc. - Fun Food
Walt Disney - Walt Disney, Inc.
The query that I already have allows me to pull row1 and 2 only  RTRIM(substring(c.companyname,0,charindex('-',c.companyname)))= LTRIM(substring(c.companyname, charindex('-',c.companyname,0)+1, len(c.companyname)))  I want a query where I can get row3 and row4 as well since these are also same first name last name cases but with a slight difference (e.g. presence of a dot(.) or an additional word (Inc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
DECLARE @CompanyNames TABLE (
    CompanyName VARCHAR(512));
INSERT INTO @CompanyNames VALUES ('Walt Disney - Walt Disney');
INSERT INTO @CompanyNames VALUES ('Fun Food - Fun Food');
INSERT INTO @CompanyNames VALUES ('Fun Food, Inc. - Fun Food');
INSERT INTO @CompanyNames VALUES ('Walt Disney - Walt Disney, Inc.');

--Split names
DECLARE @SplitNames TABLE (
    MatchLeft VARCHAR(128),
    MatchRight VARCHAR(128));
INSERT INTO 
    @SplitNames 
SELECT  
    RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CompanyName, 0, CHARINDEX('-', CompanyName))),
    LTRIM(SUBSTRING(CompanyName, CHARINDEX('-', CompanyName, 0) + 1, LEN(CompanyName)))
FROM
    @CompanyNames;

--Exact matches
SELECT 
    MatchLeft,
    MatchRight,
    CASE WHEN MatchLeft = MatchRight THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Exact
FROM 
    @SplitNames;

--Inexact matches
WITH CleansedCompanyNames AS (
    SELECT
        MatchLeft AS OriginalMatchLeft,
        MatchRight AS OriginalMatchRight,
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(MatchLeft, '.', ''), 'Inc', ''), ',', '') AS MatchLeft,
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(MatchRight, '.', ''), 'Inc', ''), ',', '') AS MatchRight
    FROM
        @SplitNames)
SELECT 
    OriginalMatchLeft,
    OriginalMatchRight,
    MatchLeft,
    MatchRight,
    CASE WHEN MatchLeft = MatchRight THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM 
    CleansedCompanyNames;

--Using SOUNDEX
SELECT 
    MatchLeft,
    MatchRight,
    CASE WHEN DIFFERENCE(MatchLeft, MatchRight) >= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Score
FROM 
    @SplitNames;
```

There are two ideas there for handling inexact matches:

- either remove punctuation and unwanted words before matching (but this will require building up a list of what to replace); or
- use SOUNDEX to test for string similarity.

Or, to use your original example, you could use this for SOUNDEX:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE
DIFFERENCE(RTRIM(substring(c.companyname,0,charindex('-',c.companyname))), LTRIM(substring(c.companyname, charindex('-',c.companyname,0)+1, len(c.companyname)))) >= 3
```

With your latest examples:

```
DECLARE @Company TABLE (
    companyname VARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO @Company VALUES ('Allen Limited - Allen Corporation');
INSERT INTO @Company VALUES ('Sweden Corp. - Sweden Corp.');
INSERT INTO @Company VALUES ('Alaska Limited - Alaska Limited, Inc.');
INSERT INTO @Company VALUES ('New York Inc. - New York Steel Limited');
INSERT INTO @Company VALUES ('India Plc - India Plc.');
INSERT INTO @Company VALUES ('Dubai International - Dubai International');
INSERT INTO @Company VALUES ('Nigera Falls Pvt. Ltd. - Amazing Nigeria Falls');
SELECT
    c.companyname,
    DIFFERENCE(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(c.companyname, 0, CHARINDEX('-', c.companyname))), LTRIM(SUBSTRING(c.companyname, CHARINDEX('-', c.companyname, 0) + 1, LEN(c.companyname)))) AS Similarity
FROM
    @Company c;
```

With results:

```
companyname Similarity
Allen Limited - Allen Corporation   4
Sweden Corp. - Sweden Corp. 4
Alaska Limited - Alaska Limited, Inc.   4
New York Inc. - New York Steel Limited  4
India Plc - India Plc.  4
Dubai International - Dubai International   4
Nigera Falls Pvt. Ltd. - Amazing Nigeria Falls  1
```

So it doesn't work so well for your last example, but seems fine for the others?

Comment: It works but I had just quoted examples in the query above. The records that I want to check are many and could be different not only because of the word 'Inc'. it could be anything - Magic Land – Magic Lands, Fun Food - Fun Food.

Comment: Which is why I provided two examples, the SOUNDEX DIFFERENCE will evaluate the similarity of two strings and should be worth a try?  Personally I would prefer a more robust distance algorithm (e.g. Jaro Winkler) but that is a bit harder to implement as it isn't built into the engine.

Comment: yes that worked with the example names that i had given.. but how do i use it if i have to select the names from a column called 'Names'. Right now we used - INSERT INTO @CompanyNames VALUES ('Fun Food - Fun Food'); I am not understanding how to use it for a column?

Comment: Where you have:

RTRIM(substring(c.companyname,0,charindex('-',c.companyname)))= LTRIM(substring(c.companyname, charindex('-',c.companyname,0)+1, len(c.companyname))) 

use:

DIFFERENCE(
RTRIM(substring(c.companyname,0,charindex('-',c.companyname))), LTRIM(substring(c.companyname, charindex('-',c.companyname,0)+1, len(c.companyname)))) >= 3

You might need to play with the numbers, 4 is the best match, 3 is okay, 2 is poor, etc.

Comment: Not working !Generate the report where texts before and after “ - “ matches = similar

Comment: Allen Limited - Allen Corporation
Sweden Corp. - Sweden Corp.
Alaska Limited - Alaska Limited, Inc.
New York Inc. - New York Steel Limited
India Plc - India Plc.
Dubai International - Dubai International
Nigera Falls Pvt. Ltd. - Amazing Nigeria Falls

Example - My NAME column in a table has the above names and thousands more. What I aim to get from the query is row2, row3,row5, row6

Comment: Yes, SOUNDEX is a bit dumb sometimes, as I said earlier you would probably be better using a more complex distance algorithm.  However, that is a LOT more work to implement...